# Conditional in TensorFlow dataset map is inconsistent with "basic" Python behavior

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Consider that I have a file `data.csv` which contains:

```
feature0,feature1,label
True,0.1,class_1
False,2.7,class_2
False,10.1,class_3
```

I would like to load this as a dataset and transform the `label` into a boolean such that it is true for `class_1` and false otherwise. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'data.csv',
    32,
    label_name='label',
    shuffle=False,
    num_epochs=1)

def view(ds, num_batches=1):
    
    for f, l in ds.take(num_batches):
        print('Features:')
        print(f)
        print('Labels:')
        print(l)

def process_labels(features, label):
    
    if label == 'class_1':
        label = True
    else:
        label = False
    
    # label = label=='class_1'
    
    return features, label

view(data.map(process_labels))
```

This throws an error: `InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 3 values, but the requested shape has 1 [[{{node Reshape}}]]`. Why is that? This is all the more confusing that when I replace the if~else with the one-liner that's commented out, `label = label=='class_1'`, the problem disappears. What's happening here?

I'm using TensorFlow 2.4.1 and Python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` is a batch size, which means that the dataset created has a the following shape: `(batch_size, feature)`. Any function that you map on that dataset should work on a batch of data, and not just on one element of the dataset.

`label = label=='class_1'` works because of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), but your previous function does not.

You have two ways of making the function work:

- either write a function that handles batches of data (i.e, your working solution)
- call [`unbatch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#unbatch) on the dataset. This may have negative performance effects, as the doc states:

  > Note: unbatch requires a data copy to slice up the batched tensor into smaller, unbatched tensors. When optimizing performance, try to avoid unnecessary usage of unbatch.

  ```
  data.unbatch().map(process_labels).batch(32)
  ```